# How to add numbers to an array in form of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string

My Question is following:
Given a number n as input, return a new string array of length n, containing the strings “0″, “1″, “2″ so on till n-1. If n=0, return an array of length 0.The expected output is-
stringArray(4) = {"0","1","2","3"} and the actual output is stringArray(4) = {0,1,2,3}.How can I add numbers in the form of string.

```
public class ArrayOfNumbers {

    static int testcase1=4;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayOfNumbers testInstance=new ArrayOfNumbers();
        String[] result=testInstance.arrayOfNumbers(testcase1);
        System.out.print("{");
        for (int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            if (i>0)
                System.out.print(",");
            System.out.print(result[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }

    public String[] arrayOfNumbers(int num) {
        int n=0;
        String n1="n";
        String[] arr=new String[num];
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
            arr[i]=n1;
            n=n+1;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to include `"` marks when you print each number?

Comment: You can use `String.valueOf()` to parse a number to a string.

Comment: @newbie don't forget to mark the post as 'solved'

Answer (score 2):

```
public String[] arrayOfNumbers(int num) {
    String[] arr=new String[num];
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        arr[i]="\"" + i + "\"";
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Also, he can get rid of n, and just use 'i' in it's place.

Comment: Add the solver marker to your post then :) Click on the cross on the left of an answer

Answer (score 2):

Change your arrayOfNumbers method,

```
public String[] arrayOfNumbers(int num) {
    String[] arr = new String[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr[i] = "\"" + String.valueOf(i) + "\"";
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Then, you could use

```
String[] result = testInstance.arrayOfNumbers(testcase1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Or (to match your output exactly) use your existing `main`.

Comment: i don't think he want to sourround his number with " ", but adding String to the array.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond Take another look at the expected output (compared to the actual output). Obviously, I *might* be wrong... I have been before, and I'm sure I will be wrong again (I just don't think I am here).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    if (i>0)
        System.out.print(",");
    System.out.print("\"" + result[i] + "\"");
}
```